# How to convert from binary to hex display in verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, hex

The question needs some explanation:

Suppose I have an 8 bit value, say **8'b00000001** (1)

Suppose I have the module as follows:

```
module hex_decoder(hex_digit, segments);
    input [3:0] hex_digit;
    output reg [6:0] segments;

    always @(*)
        case (hex_digit)
            4'h0: segments = 7'b100_0000;
            4'h1: segments = 7'b111_1001;
            4'h2: segments = 7'b010_0100;
            4'h3: segments = 7'b011_0000;
            4'h4: segments = 7'b001_1001;
            4'h5: segments = 7'b001_0010;
            4'h6: segments = 7'b000_0010;
            4'h7: segments = 7'b111_1000;
            4'h8: segments = 7'b000_0000;
            4'h9: segments = 7'b001_1000;
            4'hA: segments = 7'b000_1000;
            4'hB: segments = 7'b000_0011;
            4'hC: segments = 7'b100_0110;
            4'hD: segments = 7'b010_0001;
            4'hE: segments = 7'b000_0110;
            4'hF: segments = 7'b000_1110;   
            default: segments = 7'h7f;
        endcase
endmodule
```

to output on HEX0 and HEX1, I can do something like this:

```
hex_decoder h0(.hex_digit(value[3:0]), HEX0);
hex_decoder h1(.hex_digit(value[7:4]), HEX1);
```

and this will display **01** on HEX1, HEX0.

The only problem is that after **9**, the values will become in hex letters. I want it so that if I pass in binary 10, (**8'b00001010**), then HEX1 HEX0 should be 1 0, not 0 A (as hex works)

How can I convert it like this?

Comment: This is a non-trivial task.  One approach is to first first convert from binary to binary coded decimal.  There are various algorithms, often mirroring what you would do to convert bases by hand, and will likely involve stateful rather than only combinatorial logic.  If you want something conceptual simple but inefficient, you can even count the binary value down to zero while counting up the same number of steps in BCD.  Or you can put a big lookup table in a memory big enough to have a unique location for each possible input value.

Comment: Or you can just learn to think in hex - chances are if you're driving a 7 segment display from simple FPGA code, you're making something for personal consumption.  Actual products would use a programmable CPU, either distinct or as a soft core, for this, or else they'd produce the count natively in BCD, or even calculate arbitrary math functions in BCD like many traditional calculators did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is quite a common one - how to convert a binary number to something called "Binary Coded Decimal" (BCD). In BCD each digit is 4 bits, but those 4 bits are only used to represent the numbers 0-9 (hence the decimal bit). This is an ideal format for outputting to 7-segment displays, screens, in fact anything that needs a decimal number to be displayed.

The simplest way of converting from binary to BCD is an algorithm called "Shift-Add-3" or "Double-Dabble" (both names for the same thing). Essentially the approach is to scan through the binary representation, then any time you see a number which is 5 or higher in each group of 4 bits, you add 3 to it. This approach basically is a way to overflow any values greater or equal to 10 in a digit into the next one without too much hardware.

Here is an example, stolen from this [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble):

> `Double Dabble Conversion of 243
>   Hund Tens Unit   Shift In
>   0000 0000 0000   11110011   Initialization
>   0000 0000 0001   11100110   Shift
>   0000 0000 0011   11001100   Shift
>   0000 0000 0111   10011000   Shift
>   0000 0000 1010   10011000   Add 3 to ONES, since it was 7
>   0000 0001 0101   00110000   Shift
>   0000 0001 1000   00110000   Add 3 to ONES, since it was 5
>   0000 0011 0000   01100000   Shift
>   0000 0110 0000   11000000   Shift
>   0000 1001 0000   11000000   Add 3 to TENS, since it was 6
>   0001 0010 0001   10000000   Shift
>   0010 0100 0011   00000000   Shift
>      2    4    3
>          BCD`

Building this process in Verilog is relatively straight forward. I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Double-Dabble is that it was written for software programs, so the solution is inherently serial.  FPGA's and ASIC's are parallel in nature: we need to use their strengths to our advantage.

While Double-Dabble works, the example given here uses 11 clock cycles after initialization to arrive at a 3-digit result from an 8-bit input.  For an 8-digit result from a 27-bit input Double-Dabble requires 35 clock cycles.  A reachable goal for an N-digit result is N-1 clock cycles.  How?  By doing long division in parallel.

For an eight digit result from a 27-bit input, start by doing 9 subtractions in parallel, input1 minus: 9000_0000, 8000_0000, 7000_0000, ..., 2000_0000, 1000_0000 and implicit 0.  Take the remainder from largest factor where the result is not negative (test the top bit of the result), record the factor as the top digit and use the remainder as the input to the next stage, which is again 9 subtractions in parallel.  Input2 minus 900_0000, 800_0000, 700_0000, ..., 200_0000, 100_0000 and implicit 0. Repeat this procedure down to input7 minus 90, 80, 70, ..., 20 and 10.  The remainder from the last subtraction is the one's digit.

Using this method requires seven clock cycles after initialization for an eight digit result.  Depending on the FPGA, this might be implemented with nine DSP's and 63 constants.  Without DSP's, the number of bits of subtraction go down by three or four bits on every cycle, so it does not take as much fabric as you might expect, and it still only requires seven clock cycles to complete.

Answer (score 0):

A rom table could work if you like using up FPGA gates.... Say you have a typical FPGA dev board with four 7 segment displays, and you want to show unsigned values. That's 10000 total characters, 7 bits each, round up to 16K by 32 bits is a 64 Kbyte rom.
(The 7 seg beside me also has a decimal LED, so 8 bits per character..)

Something like a "character generator" from the stone age of ascii terminals.

You can also use up one 7 seg and get from 9999 down to -999.

Filling the rom table can be done by C or Python etc using one of the above and converting the output to the FPGA rom file format..

At FPGA speeds this is *slightly*(!!)
 more than a bit faster than needed and thus a waste of gates, but if you have space why not?

Definitely fast enough for Persistence of Vision games..

Typically though, if you already have a small embedded microprocessor, use one of the sequential routines above and let the micro handle it as one of its' tasks..